# Versioning specific text / code (R) files on Windows

Tags: windows, version-control, ide

I find myself editing R code files on Windows using RStudio. But often I want to keep previous versions in case I make a mistake and want to roll back to a previous version etc.

Right now RStudio offers no native way to do this. I end up doing this manually saving files like `"foo.R"` `"foo_bkup_jan17_6pm.R"` etc.

Is there a program that will let me do this without cluttering up my directories like this? When I used to work on a linux machine I had bazaar do this pretty well for me.

Any thoughts about a good application / workflow to do this?

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN for nice integration, any SCM (even Bazaar) for versioning by hands

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different tools available for this. What you're looking for is a version control system.

Examples would include [SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/) and (more popular these days) [GIT](https://git-scm.com/) which probably would work.

Personally I'd use GIT. There are quite a few GUIs available for it. The current Visual Studio has integration and [Atlassian SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree) provides an easy to use interface. This solution would add a hidden `.git` directory to your project directory and you would have to manually check it in.

An alternative approach would be to use the Windows [Previous Version](http://www.howtogeek.com/56891/use-windows-7s-previous-versions-to-go-back-in-time-and-save-your-files/) feature. This would enable you restore items in a Windows native way. The versioning wouldn't be as explicit and you wouldn't be able to store a useful comment with it.

Comment: The TortoiseSVN client can create a local "file://” repository which can be committed to in the same way as a normal repository without the need for a remote server.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. it's been ages since I used SVN. I removed the false statement.